# Card game Sets in Processing

Tags: processing

i'm trying to make a card game called sets ([Here a link to how it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game))). I need to create 27 cards (array) and then check each time take 12 cards out of it and get the pairs. Does anyone know the best way to search for pairs. Like to check which cards:
They all have the same number or have three different numbers.
They all have the same symbol or have three different symbols.
They all have the same color or have three different colors.

How can i use the wright datatype in the array and later check which is the good one in a function

I tried using a array with strings which contains the color, shape and amount. Like green triangle 3x times is: gt3. But i cant find out how to compare them for the good pairs

Comment: You've tagged your post as both Java and Processing. Which one is relevant?

Comment: The "best" way? In what sense? Have you tried to solve it yourself in *any* way?

Comment: @AndrewFan i edited it which answers your questions

Comment: @Gendarme i changed the text with what i tried too do

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/make-the-game-called-sets/7761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, that you can implement right away is using a 2D-array.

You learned that an array can hold values. An array can also hold other arrays. So you can use an array per card to hold the properties, and store all those arrays in a 'cardset' array. You can now access the individual card properties by using 2 indexes. The code below can help you understand:

```
String[] card_a = {"G", "T","3"};
String[] card_b = {"R", "S","2"};
String[] card_c = {"G", "S","1"};

String[][] cardset = {card_a, card_b, card_c};

void setup(){
  //Print the number on card_a
  print(cardset[0][2]);
  //Compare the number on card_a with the number on card_b
  if(cardset[0][2] == cardset[1][2]){
  print("Equal!");
  }
  else{
  print("Unequal!");
  }
}
```

You can also instantiate a 2D-array directly like this:

```
String[][] cardset = {  {"G", "T","3"},
                        {"R", "S","2"},
                        {"G", "S","1"}
                      };
```

The long answer is that you should learn about the power of objects.
I won't fully explain it, because that would be very lengthy and the internet is full of excellent explanations - better than mine would ever be.

I suggest you read [this tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/) on the processing website. I can also advice [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/playlists?sort=dd&shelf_id=2&view=50) on the basics of both processing and programming, including objects.

The code below shows you what a basic implementation of an object can look like. This might not make a whole lot of sense to you yet. That's okay. Objects are a fundamental programming principle, but it takes some time - and a good explanation - to get your head around. Therefor I highly suggest you check out the tutorials I posted above. It will probably take some time before you fully master the concept, but when you do, you can harness its power.

```
class Card {

  String shape;
  int number;
  color col;

  Card(String s, int n, color c) {
    shape = s;
    number = n;
    col = c;
  }
  }

  void setup() {

    color red = color(255, 0, 0);
    color green = color(0, 255, 0);
    color blue = color(0, 0, 255);

    Card a = new Card("Circle", 1, red);
    Card b = new Card("Square", 2, green);
    Card c = new Card("Circle", 3, blue);

    //Check for equal shapes
    if (a.shape == b.shape && b.shape ==c.shape ) {
      print("All shapes equal");
    }

    //Check for unequal shapes
    if (a.shape != b.shape && a.shape != c.shape && b.shape !=c.shape ) {
      print("All shapes unequal");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much the last part will work perfect for what i want. Also the link helps thanks